# Identifying degrees of freedom.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I solved a problem earlier in an inefficient way, I am trying to understand if there is a way to know that I am being inefficient.

The problem was to find when the sum of two fractions equals the product of two fractions.

I modeled the problem as $\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{ac}{bd}$

which I changed to $\dfrac{ad}{bd}+\dfrac{bc}{bd} = \dfrac{ac}{bd}$

giving $ad+bc=ac$

and solved to get $a=\dfrac{bc}{c-d}$

At this point I wrongly assumed that there were $4$ degrees of freedom and the equation reduced it to $3$. Looking back I noticed that if I instead rearranged to $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{c}{c-d}$ I could eliminate 2 variables in one go creating the much simpler equation $\dfrac{c}{d} + \dfrac{c}{c-d}$. This made me conclude that I had introduced too many variables so I looked back at the problem and found that I could have modeled the problem as $\dfrac{e}{g}+\dfrac{f}{g}$ or $\dfrac{h}{i}+\dfrac{h}{j}$.

*What tools / methods are available for finding how many degrees of freedom are needed? How could I have known before solving the problem that I had too many variables?*

Comment: The so called much  simpler equation is not an equation.

Comment: One equation with four variables leaves three independent variables.  Degrees of freedom is a physics term.